# Facebook wall post not working after access token key required

Tags: jquery, facebook, access-token

Im using a jquery script that grabs my posts from facebook and then displays on my site. Here is the code Im using:

http://www.neosmart.de/social-media/facebook-wall

Facebook now requires an access token in order to access your feed. So I created an app under my facebook login and then grabbed the access token. Once I pass the access token it shows the posts on my wall on my site. However the second I log out of Facebook the posts on my site no longer show, instead it shows this error:

```
Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out.
```

So my question is what are the proper steps to get an access token from my facebook account that I can use to view my facebook feed if Im logged into facebook or not?

**EDIT:**

This is a step by step explanation of what to do to grant myself permission to my own app with offline access and get the access token. Once I followed these steps my feed now works as it should.

http://itslennysfault.com/get-facebook-access-token-for-graph-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to ask Facebook for the "offline_access" permission when getting an access token.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to figure it out, since what you said was correct I will mark this as the answer. But I updated my original post to show the steps I had to take to get this working.